# bash substring working in interpreter mode but not in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, aix

When I try to do a substring in bash shell in interpreter mode, I get expected output

```
bash-4.2$ x="SomeString"
bash-4.2$ echo $x
SomeString
bash-4.2$ y=${x:0:4}
bash-4.2$ echo $y
Some
bash-4.2$
```

whereas while running the same commands in a shell script, I get an error.

```
bash-4.2$ cat shell.sh
x="SomeString"
echo $x
y=${x:0:4}
echo $y

bash-4.2$ sh shell.sh
SomeString
shell.sh[3]: y=${x:0:4}: 0403-011 The specified substitution is not valid for this command.
bash-4.2$
```

The irony is that when I invoke the shell by `bash-4.2$ ./shell.sh`, it's working.

What's happening here?

I'm on an **AIX** machine.

Comment: `/bin/sh` != `/bin/bash`

Comment: Bash behaves differently when invoked as [`/bin/sh` or `sh`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-POSIX-Mode).  And on some systems, `/bin/sh` is not the same as `/bin/bash` at all; it might be `dash` or the original Bourne shell, or ...  On AIX, `/bin/sh` is probably a Korn shell.  At least, on the AIX machine I'm using right now, `/bin/sh` and `/bin/ksh` have the same inode number.  Start your script with the appropriate shebang: `#!/bin/bash` or whatever is the correct path to Bash,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Substrings are a `bash` extension. When you run it as `sh`, it disables this extension. Use `bash shell.sh` and it will work.

You should also put `#!/bin/bash` at the beginning of the script, to ensure that it runs with `bash` when you invoke it as a command.